# One IP two virtual machines

Tags: apache, virtual-machine

I have 2 virtual machines with 2 Apache. I've just one public IP.

It's possible to redirect with the domain name to machine 1 or machine 2, with the same port?

Example:

```
domain a.com points to machine 1 (10.0.0.1)
domain b.com points to machine 2 (10.0.0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a reverse proxy. HAProxy would be a fine choice, with a config looking something like

```
frontend fe
    bind *:80
    capture request hdr(host) len 255
    use_backend a if { hdr(host) -i -m dom a.com }
    use_backend b if { hdr(host) -i -m dom b.com }
    default_backend invalid

backend a
    server a 10.0.0.1:80

backend b
    server b 10.0.0.2:80

backend invalid
    http-response deny
```

If you want to support SSL (TLS) and you don't already have termination somewhere upstream, then HAProxy will need to have your certificate so it can terminate the connections and get access to the hostname; you'll have to configure that, and add `use_backend` rules conditional on `ssl_fc_sni`.